# Show only some of the objects in an Array

Tags: ios, xcode, nsarray, restkit

I want to **only show some of the items** in an array, but can't figure out how to do it.

This is the code I have that currently shows all objects in the array:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *springs;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *leafs;


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"standardCell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    Spring *spring = [springs objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];  // 13 objects
    Leaf *leaf = [spring.leafs objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];  // 30 objects

    cell.textLabel.text = league.shortName;
    return cell;
}
```

So I would like to only show **5 of the 30** leaf objects from that array I created, and not show all of them.  Is there any way to do that?

(I'm using an API to pull the items into the Array)

Thanks for the help, will post any specific code or other info needed!

**EDIT**
Added per request:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    Spring *spring = [springs objectAtIndex:section];
    return spring.leafs.count;
}
```

I'm using RestKit for the object mapping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `[NSArray objectsAtIndexes:]` ([reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSArray/objectsAtIndexes%3a)) to get a subset of the array.

```
Leaf *leaf = [spring.leafs objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; 

// This will include objects 0-4:
NSRange range = NSMakeRange(0, 5);
NSArray *subset = [leaf objectsAtIndexes:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndexesInRange:range]];
```

Just adjust `range` to whatever start/length you want in the subset.

EDIT: Of course any subset logic in this method will also have to be duplicated in the `numberOfRowsInSection:` delegate method, else your app with throw an exception.

Comment: Thanks for the response, this makes a lot of sense, however when I tried it, the `NSRange` line gave me an error saying "Initializing `NSRange` with an expression of incompatible type `NSRange`... any idea why?

Comment: @Reez No, I don't understand that.  You could forget about `NSMakeRange()` and just set `range.location` and `range.length` explicitly.

Comment: I made range a pointer instead of a struct, my bad.  The problem I'm having now though is that for my textLabel I can't use `league.shortName` anymore, but yet I can't use just `subset.shortName` either, so what would I use?  Thx again-

Comment: @Reez There's an error somewhere else which is out-of-scope of this question I'm afraid (it's unrelated).

Comment: From what I can tell it seems to just have to do with the fact that I can't call a property `shortName` on the newly created array `subset` now, where as I could do it with `league` before.

Comment: If you have any idea why that might be just let me know so I can solve this problem, if not thanks for the help anyway even if think its outside the scope of this question-

Comment: @Reez sorry, I have no idea

Answer (score 1):

How about in your `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection`, don't return a full count full spring.leafs?  For instance,

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 5;
}
```

Are you trying to lazy load them, or do the rest of them just not matter?  Good luck.

Comment: The rest of them just don't matter.  Thanks for the response!  What I'm getting when I tried to return 5 was a crash with the message '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 1 beyond bounds [0 .. 0]'

Comment: Yeah, the array is empty.  Check your method where you're populating the array and see why it's no being populated.

Comment: Just shooting in the dark, is `leafs` instantiated as an NSMutableArray?

Comment: The array isn't empty in my original code for it, but just when I do the `return 5;`... so I'm trying to figure out how to mash up my original code with yours.  Any thoughts?

Comment: Yeah, I've got that in my code above that it is a NSMutableArray.  Do I need to just make that an NSArray?